# Get value of dictionary<string, string> from hidden field to post method in asp.net mvc

Tags: dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5, model, controller

I am creating a web app in which I need to get the value of my `public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }` in post method

here is how my code looks,

My model -> `public Dictionary<string, string> KeyValuePairs { get; set; }`

the above property is included in my model

```
@{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model.KeyValuePairs)
    {
        <input type="hidden" value="@item.Key" name="@Model.KeyValuePairs.ElementAt(index).Key" />
        <input type="hidden" value="@item.Value" name="@Model.KeyValuePairs.ElementAt(index).Value" id="@index" />
        index++;
    }
}
```

I am storing all the key value of `Dictionary<string, string>` but still showing as empty in my controller post event,

I also Tried Like below

```
@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Model.KeyValuePairs)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="KeyValuePairs[@index].key" value="@kvp.Key" />
    <input type="hidden" name="KeyValuePairs[@index].Value" value="@kvp.Value" />
    index++;
}
```

What I need to do to get the Dictionary in Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `name="@Model.KeyValuePairs.ElementAt(index).Key"` is fetching the value. It should be `name="Model.KeyValuePairs[@index].Key"` then it will bind data to model.

Checkout my below code to understand more clearly.

Model

```
public class KeyValuePairs {
     public Dictionary<string, string> DictList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PassDictionary(KeyValuePairs model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("PassDictionary");
}
```

View

```
@model Project.Web.Models.KeyValuePairs

@using (Html.BeginForm("PassDictionary", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { })) {

    // I have changed foreach to forloop so no need to declare index 
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.DictList.Count; i++) {

    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.DictList.ElementAt(i).Key" name="Model.DictList[@i].Key" />
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.DictList.ElementAt(i).Value" name="Model.DictList[@i].Value" />

   }
   <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
}
```